# Web Hosting for Docker Containters

Tags: docker

I have a Windows VM, which is hosting many websites using IIS, I am using IIS HOST-HEADERS (So I can use same IP for all websites).

Now I want to run some containers on my Windows VM Server. I can pull the Image on my VM and run it on a different port locally, however my question is how can I run multiple docker containers  on my Windows machine each using same port 80 and 443 (Same I was doing with IIS).

Comment: You can have a container with a -webserver- reverse proxy like Nginx routing the requests to the other containers that have the applications.

Comment: you mean reverse proxy? i believe IIS has reverse proxy feature as well.

Comment: oops, yes, a reverse proxy. you can create the rules and route the requests to each container depending on the path, header. I did not use IIS too much.